# How to pass variables between steps inside a transformation in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

I want to design a ETL job as attached.[image]

Step 1 will set two variables `Variable_1` and `Variable_2`. I am using `Generate Rows` step for doing this where I define both variables in `Fields`.

Step 2 will read a date from database through a SQL query. I am using `Table input` to achieve this. And the sql is like `select Variable_3 from table1` which is a single value. Preview here shows that the value is read successfully from database.

I want step 3 as `Modified Java Script Value` where I want to use these 3 variables and do some calculation to derive the output Variable_4 which I then want to pass on to future transformation for use there.

I am new to Pentaho and have the following questions:

1) When I connect Step 2 (database step) to Step 3 (Javascript step), I get a warning dialog box:

> We detected rows with varying number of fields, this is not allowed in
>   a transformation. The first row contained 2 fields, another one
>   contained 1

What does this warning mean? What am I doing wrong? How can I pass 2 variables from 1st step and 1 from 2nd step to my javascript step?

2) How do I set the calculated Variable_4 in my Javascript step for further use in other transformation? Do I define a Parameter on `Transformation 1` named `Variable_4` and set it from javascript? If yes, how?

Comment: @Kamil G.: Can you please check my new question. I used "Add Constant Values" after Step 2 and removed Step 1... and its working as expected... however, I am not able to setVariable the generated Variable_4 inside my Javascript step...

Comment: I've answered your newest question.

Comment: @KamilG.: Have one more issue... have put it in comments of the same question..  please check when you can.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the first step (Generate Rows creating two variables) and put in a Add Constants step after Table View step to add Variable 1 and Variable 2 along side Variable 3 passed to it from the Table View step.

Finally, I have all 3 of my variables available in my Javascript step.

I am still not been able to figure out Question 2) though.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your variable in the beginning of the script as:

var Variable_4

then press the 'get variables' button at the bottom and your fieldname Variable_4 appears which enables it for further usage